# UIActivityIndicatorView not showing for duration of async task

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous, uiactivityindicatorview, swift2

I'm working on an app in iOS wherein I need to start spinning a UIActivityIndicatorView, upload an image to a server, and when the upload is completed, stop spinning the activity indicator.

I'm currently using XCode 7 Beta and am testing the app on the iOS simulator as an iPhone 6 and iPhone 5. My issue is that the activity indicator won't end immediately after file upload, but several (~28 seconds) later. Where should I place my calls to cause it to end?

I have an @IBOutlet function attached to the button I use to start the process, which contains the startAnimating() function, and which calls a dispatch_async method that contains the call to uploadImage, which contains the signal, wait, and stopAnimating() functions.

Note that

```
let semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0)
let priority = DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH
```

are defined at the top of my class.

```
@IBAction func uploadButton(sender: AnyObject) {

        self.activityIndicatorView.startAnimating()
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(priority, 0)) {

         self.uploadImage(self.myImageView.image!)

        }  // end dispatch_async

    }   // works with startAnimating() and stopAnimating() in async but not with uploadImage() in async


    func uploadImage(image: UIImage) {

        let request = self.createRequest(image)

        let session : NSURLSession = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

        let task : NSURLSessionTask = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {
            (data, response, error) in

            if error != nil {
                print(error!.description)
            } else {
                let httpResponse: NSHTTPURLResponse = response as! NSHTTPURLResponse

                if httpResponse.statusCode != 200 {
                    print(httpResponse.description)
                } else {

                    print("Success! Status code == 200.")
                    dispatch_semaphore_signal(self.semaphore)
                    }
            }
        })! // end dataTaskWithResult

        task.resume()

        dispatch_semaphore_wait(self.semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER)
        self.activityIndicatorView.stopAnimating()
    } // end uploadImage
```

This is just one version of my code, I have moved several things around several different ways. I have tried this:

```
@IBAction func uploadButton(sender: AnyObject) {

        self.activityIndicatorView.startAnimating()
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(priority, 0)) {

         self.uploadImage(self.myImageView.image!)
         dispatch_semaphore_signal(self.semaphore)
        }  // end dispatch_async
    dispatch_semaphore_wait(self.semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER)
    self.activityIndicatorView.stopAnimating()
    }
```

And several, several other ways of moving my code around to attempt to get the activity indicator to display for the duration of the image upload and then immediately quit. In some cases the spinner doesn't appear at all for the duration of program execution. I read [this](http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-tutorials/82677-how-to-display-an-activity-indicator-or-other-ui-before-beginning-a-long-task.html) post and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24944793/uiactivityindicatorview-does-not-show-start-animating) question and have migrated my dispatch_semaphore_wait and stopAnimating() to the uploadImage() method to circumvent this, but can't find enough information in the UIActivityIndicatorView documentation about the UI updating to know any other way of updating it, though I believe this might be at the core of the problem.

All I need is for the spinner to start before the upload process begins (dataTaskWithRequest) and end once it has succeeded or failed. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using semaphores, you could just dispatch directly to the main thread in your async task,

```
func uploadImage(image: UIImage) {
    let request = self.createRequest(image)
    let session : NSURLSession = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    let task : NSURLSessionTask = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {
        (data, response, error) in

        if error != nil {
            print(error!.description)
        } else {
            let httpResponse: NSHTTPURLResponse = response as! NSHTTPURLResponse

            if httpResponse.statusCode != 200 {
                print(httpResponse.description)
            } else {
                print("Success! Status code == 200.")
            }
        }

        // dispatch to main thread to stop activity indicator
        dispatch_async(disptach_get_main_queue()) {
            self.activityIndicatorView.stopAnimating()
        }
    })! // end dataTaskWithResult

    task.resume()
} // end uploadImage
```

Comment: This fixes the issue, though I'm incredibly frustrated at why exactly semaphores aren't working. Is there a reason in my code?

Comment: I don't know enough about semaphores to answer that. With the limited knowledge I have, your code looks right. But sometimes GCD just makes life easier.

Comment: I don't think anything about the semaphore code you are using causes the call to `self.activityIndicatorView.stopAnimating` to be performed on the main thread. Keith's solution of using `dispatch_async(disptach_get_main_queue()` is the correct answer. (voted)

Comment: the solution is not valid for synchronous request. What if some one want to do synchronous call using semaphore. Same problem will appear again.